# get referring url from my rest api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

I am building a rest api in mvc. When consuming the API, I need to be able to get the referring URL that is calling the service.  I have tried Request.UrlReferer and it comes back null.  How can I get the url that is consuming the service?

Comment: This is a little unclear, you need the consumer of the REST endpoint to know the URL of the consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you don't mean in the consumer you need to know the referer of the client making the REST call?

If this is the case what you need to do is look at the `request header` and extract from it the `Referer`.

Comment: Yes, I needed the url from the client making the REST call. Thank you for your speedy help. My apologies for not being clear.

Comment: The referer is returning null.  I pulled the entire headers and did not see a referer.

'WebRequest offerRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL) as WebRequest; 
WebResponse offerResponse = offerRequest.GetResponse(); 
var reader = new StreamReader(offerResponse.GetResponseStream()); 
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
var obj = reader.ReadToEnd();'

Comment: I was able to get the IP address which will work as well...I used
Request.UserHostName